# Why does drawing a shape to a bitmap reduce quality?

Tags: android

Why does drawing a shape to a bitmap cause the shape to be blurry versus drawing the shape straight to the canvas?

Comment: it doesn't: drawing is drawing - in both cases you are using the `Canvas`

Comment: Are you sure? I currently drawing a bunch of shapes to a bitmap and then drawing that bitmap to a canvas and the shapes are not nearly as sharp as if I were to draw the shapes directly to the canvas without the bitmap.

Comment: post your code then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitmap is a [rasterized computer image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics), consisting of points (pixels).

The Canvas class holds the "draw" calls.

A shape is an abstract definition of shape (vector-like).

> drawing the shape straight to the canvas

That's not accurate, maybe you mean straight to the screen of device, which is Bitmap too.

To use [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) for drawing, you need the canvas to host the calls, some bitmap as target, and some drawing primitive (shape is one), and Paint (contains information how to paint the drawing primitive).

Once you draw some shape into the target bitmap, it will be aliased to the pixels of target bitmap. Ie. an circle will turn into some approximation created by rectangular pixels of target bitmap.

What you probably see in your particular case is, that your Bitmap has lower resolution than screen, and when you draw that low-res bitmap to the target screen bitmap, it is upscaled by some filter which makes the upscaled picture a bit blurry to avoid big rectangular pixelation (or it may be also other way, downscaling hi-res bitmap, which contains too sharp/thin contours, which will be aliased second time when downscaled, and even with anti-aliasing filtering it will get blurred a bit). Or maybe you use some paint with settings causing blur (unlikely, can't think of creating one by accident, you would knew).

If you will use for both targets Bitmap of identical density (resolution of single pixel), and the same paint method, then the result will be same, and also drawing the shape from bitmap to bitmap as long as you will use whole pixel coordinates/size, and no filtering, again the result will be same as drawing directly to screen bitmap.

So start first by checking the size of your bitmap vs screen bitmap, and then check paint settings and additional canvas arguments to draw the bitmap, whether you don't upscale/downscale it with some kind of filtering.

Comment: Thanks, I think the cause is likely that the bitmap is being downscaled due to it being 1920 x 1920 and my target screen size being 1080 x 1920

Comment: @Shpanders try identical sizes first, to see if there's not involved some additional filtering in the paint bitmap draw method (like drawing same size at scale 1.0, but at 0.5,0.5 position, for example, that would with some drawing engines/settings cause some filtering to kick in to move the original by half a pixel). ... If 1.0 scale drawing is crisp, you may consider drawing only cut-out area (ignoring the area outside of screen size) 1080x1920 of the 1920x1920 to be drawn, but maybe you can just start with screen size bitmap in the first place.